# Any ideas how I can rewire my brain such that $\varphi \leq \psi$ "obviously" means that $\varphi$ implies $\psi$?

Tags: logic, soft-question, self-learning

The Boolean domain $B=\{\mathrm{False},\mathrm{True}\},$ can be viewed as a partially ordered set in two different ways. In the best approach, $\mathrm{False}$ is the least element and $\mathrm{True}$ is the greatest element. This has the effect that the lattice operations $\wedge$ and $\vee$ agree with their usual (logical) definitions; furthermore, we deduce (under this convention) that $\varphi \leq \psi$ iff $\varphi \rightarrow \psi = \mathrm{True},$ as desired. Thus, let us hereafter agree to order the Boolean domain in this way.

The problem is this. Whenever I'm thinking about the Boolean domain, I tend to think of its elements as *conditions.* So for example, since $\mathrm{True}$ is the weakest condition, I tend to think of $\mathrm{True}$ as the *least* element. But this contradicts the aforementioned ordering; we agreed that $\mathrm{True}$ should be the *greatest* element!

The same issue occurs when $B$ is replaced by any other poset of sentences, such as the sentences of the first-order language of arithmetic. I always get confused, because I tend to think of those sentences as *conditions*, and therefore I read $\varphi \leq \psi$ to mean "$\varphi$ is a weaker condition than $\psi$." (Bad!)

So, I'd like to rewire my brain so that "$\varphi$ is less than $\psi$" *intuitively* means "$\varphi$ implies $\psi$."

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Thirty years of computer programming did it for me. FALSE is 0 and TRUE is 1.

Comment: Maybe think of $\leq$ similarily as $\subseteq$ ? I think the analogy between the logic $\leq$ and set theory $\subseteq$ is more consistent than the analogy between numeric $\leq$ and logic $\leq$...

Comment: @Olivier, its a good suggestion, but hasn't worked for me so far. The problem is that when I read a mathematical formula, I parse it as as *formula*, not as the set of all its instances in some particular universe.

Comment: You could try reading $A \le B$ as "$A$ is no more true than $B$".

Comment: The best approach of course is to make $\bot$ the top element, not the bottom. Then stronger statements are higher in the lattice.

Comment: @CarlMummert, I strongly considered doing just that, but my concern is that it may create as many problems as it solves. Sure, its more intuitive; *but* for example it means that (1) $\wedge$ means "or", and that (2) $\top$ either denotes "false," or that it denotes true but it is now the least element (violating order-theoretic conventions), and that (3) $A \cup B = \{x : (x \in A) \wedge (x \in B)\}$, and also that (4) $\varphi \leq \psi$ iff $\{x : \varphi(x)\} \supseteq \{x : \psi(x)\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't convince that part of your brain with insight, you could try to trick it with language alone, by inserting truth-bearing adjectives into the "less than":

- $\varphi$ is less evident than $\psi$
- $\varphi$ is less general than $\psi$
- $\varphi$ is less accommodating than $\psi$
- $\varphi$ is less broadly applicable than $\psi$
- $\varphi$ is less often true than $\psi$
- $\varphi$ is less likely than $\psi$
- $\varphi$ is less certain than $\psi$
- $\varphi$ is less justifiable than $\psi$
- $\varphi$ is less obvious than $\psi$

This isn't a good standalone solution, because it's blindly fighting language with language. You still need some guiding principle to help you avoid truth-*forming* adjectives like "strong", "strict", "interesting", "informative", or "useful". Maybe you can use one of the other answers to kick out the misleading adjectives, and then you can cement the victory by replacing it with a better adjective?

Comment: Excellent answer.

Answer (score 4):

“$\varphi$ implies $\psi$” means the following:

- If $\varphi$ is true, then $\psi$ must be true. That is, if $\varphi=1$, then $\psi=1$ (using the notation as in the answer of @nbubis).
- If $\varphi$ is false, then $\psi$ may be either false or true. That is, if $\varphi=0$, then either $\psi=0$ or $\psi=1$.

Can you now see why the implication condition is equivalent to requiring that $\varphi\leq\psi$?

Comment: I'm still not finding it intuitive though. After all, $0$ is nothing right? So we cannot prove anything from $0$. But wait; we can prove *everything* from $0$.

Comment: I think you are referring to a seemingly slight but very important distinction. We cannot _prove_ everything from a false statement; what _is_ true that everything is logically _consistent_ with a false statement. That is, suppose that $\varphi$ is false. Can we conclude that $\psi$ is true? Hell, no! It does mean, however, that the statement “$\varphi\Longrightarrow\psi$” is true, irrespective of whether $\psi$ is true of false!

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with what you're saying; to me, if $\varphi$ is false, then assuming $\varphi$, we're permitted to conclude that $\psi$ is true. However, we must realize that our conclusion that $\psi$ is true only applies inside universes where $\varphi$ is true, which is to say, nowhere.

Comment: However, the point I think I was trying to make is that $0$ is kind of reminiscent of an empty list of assumptions; from which we cannot conclude anything new. On the other hand, from $0$=false we can conclude *everything* new.

Comment: @user18921 Whenever $\varphi$ is false, the statement “_if_ $\varphi$ is true, _then_ so is $\psi$” is true. But we cannot conclude that $\psi$ is true, because $\varphi$ being false is consistent with either truth value of $\psi$. But I do see your point. If you assume a false statement, then you can arrive at another, not necessarily true, conclusion. Intuitively, if you go crazy a little bit by assuming just one false statement, then it is “logically justified” for you to go fully crazy and assume anything.

Answer (score 2):

Learn how to program. Then, it will become clearer that: $$\rm{false} = 0 < 1 = \rm{true}$$

Comment: Many actual systems use 1 to signal false and 0 to signal true. Google for "negative logic"

Comment: @CarlMummert - I specifically mentioned programming - I am not aware of any major language where this "true" is not $1$.

Answer (score 1):

It is the ordering by "amount of evidence for (statement)", or "range of possible situations in which (statement) is true".

If $A \to B$ then any piece of evidence for $A$ is automatically evidence for $B$.  This becomes a theorem if the evidence for $A$ is defined as the set of statements that imply $A$, and ordering of evidence is by inclusion of the sets.

If $A \to B$, then any situation where $A$ is true (considering only situations in which the logical rules leading from $A$ to $B$ hold) is one where $B$ is true.  If there is a completeness theorem for the logic then having one statement hold in a superset of the models where another holds, is equivalent to syntactic implication of one statement by the other, connecting the idea to the previous definition.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of $\varphi \leq \psi$ as a sort of containment, $\varphi \subset \psi$. That is, $\varphi$ is a special case of $\psi$, so the former implies the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Well, weaker statements follow (logically) from stronger statements, just as later elements follow (in order) the earlier ones. In that sense, it's natural that the strongest statement should be first in the tree, while the weakest should be last.